# ASP.NET MVC2 TeplatedHelper doesn't render an ID of the HTML's markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have the code (snippet):

The Model is the IEnumerable object of the Person's class:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) 
  { %>
     <tr>
         <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x=>item.Name) %></td>
     </tr>    
<% } %>
```

it renders only labels like that:

```
<td>Tommy</td>
```

According to the [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx) it should be rendering a HTML markup something like:

[image]

but there is no the ID and the NAME property. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

Your using the wrong template your should be using `Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)`

**Edit:** I said you were using the wrong template because in your image it is a textbox displayed, not a label...

the default ouptut of Displayfor is

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.Encode(ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue) %>
```

according to [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+BradWilson+%28Brad+Wilson%29&utm_content=Google+Reader). You could easily build your own, look the other post of Brad Wilson for examples.

Or you could simply call `Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)`

If you always want that, add a template, name String.ascx in your Views/Share/DisplayTemplate and just put the following in :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.Label("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue) %>
```